# Sysprep could not complete

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, login, sysprep

I recently had to change the SID on my virtual machine.
After a reboot I got this error message:

[image]

I opened the Microsoft Management console (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> » mmc) and head over to *user* and *local computer policy*. The administrator account status is disabled and I cannot enable it.

[image]

I already have an administrator account and the option *disable the account*  is not checked.

I can logon by:

- typing services.msc and starting all the necessery services.
- running explorer.exe
- switching the user
- logging in to my account.

But when I reboot the situation repeats and the first error occurs again.

Do you know what should I do to get my windows working again?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue last week when creating new sysprep images to replace older ones. My issue was two-fold. The first issue was NVIDIA display drivers had auto-installed when I ran windows update, and this caused issues with older NVIDIA models to BSOD while starting services. I reprepped another machine and uninstalled the video drivers before sysprepping and that fixed that issue.

The second issue had to do with joining the domain before sysprepping. This was the cause of my installation crashing while starting up services, because it was attempting to use the domain administration account, but the PC had not yet joined the domain. I sysprepped yet another machine, this time being sure not to join the domain and everything worked without a hitch.

I also tried the same GPO settings you spoke of with the same results.

I sysprepped with /oobe /generalize /shutdown /unattend:unattend.xml, then uploaded to our WDS server. Installs now complete successfully from the WDS server.